# How to return a value based on column value and Timestamp using user-defined function in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, valueerror

I have two dataframe, which I have joined. On the joined Dataframe, I'm writing a user-defined function where based on Timestamp and the value count of the column i need to return the value based on the condition mentioned below create a new column called "Day_Sentiment". But I'm getting below error. Please let me know how to go about it

Input:

```
                  Date          Content    Cleaned-content   Sentiment   
                  11/12/2020    abb        bbc abb           Bad         
                  12/10/2020    xyz        xxy               Good        
                  11/24/2020    tyu        yuu               Neutral     
                  12/16/2020    iop        yui               Bad
```

Output:

```
               Date          Content    Cleaned-content   Sentiment   Day_Sentiment
               11/12/2020    abb        bbc abb           Bad         Bad
               12/10/2020    xyz        xxy               Good        Bad
               11/24/2020    tyu        yuu               Neutral     Bad
               12/16/2020    iop        yui               Bad         Bad
```

So far I tried below:

```
df = input_data.join(results)

def compare_def(df):

    no.bad_senti= df.loc[df['Sentiment'] == 'Bad']
    no.neut_senti = df.loc[df['Sentiment'] == 'Neutral']
    no.good_senti= df.loc[df['Sentiment'] == 'Good']

    if ((no.bad_senti> no.good_senti) & (no.bad_senti> no.neut_senti)):
       output = 'Bad'
    elif ((no.good_senti> no.bad_senti) & (no.good_senti> no.neut_senti)):
       output= 'Good'
    elif ((no.neut_senti> no.bad_senti) & (no.neut_senti> no.good_senti)):
       output= 'Neutral'
    elif no.good_senti== no.bad_senti:
       output= 'Neutral'
    elif no.bad_senti== no.neut_senti:
       output= 'bad'
    elif no.good_senti== no.neut_senti:
       output= 'good'
    else:
       output= 'Neutral'

    return output

df['Day_Sentiment'] = output
```

Alternate:

```
 output = compare_def(df)
 df['Day_Sentiment'] = output
```

Error:

```
     ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled DataFrame objects
```

Example 1:
Predicted Sentiments
Sentiment
2 bad
1 good
1 Neutral

Then in function
2 > 1 and 2 > 1
returns Bad

Example 2:
Sentiment:
2 bad
5 good
5 neutral

Function:

2 > 5
false
5 > 2 and 5 > 5
false
5 > 2 and 5 > 5
false
5==2
false
2==5
false
5==5
True
return good

Answer (score 0):

There Several issues with your code.  To begin the variables bad, good, & neut are Panda Series  of different lengths containing string variables.  You then attempt to evaluate perform several conditional tests for example `if ((bad> good) & (bad> neut)` which generates your ValueError.  I am not quite sure what logic you are attempting to implement, but the following template may help:

```
def compare_data(row):
    value = 'Good'
    # The logic here escapes me
    # Evaluate the row contents of row[Sentiment] and modify value
    return value  

df["Day Sentiment"]= df.apply(lambda row: compare_data(row), axis= 1)
```

Yields:

```
    Date    Content Cleaned-content Sentiment   Day Sentiment
0   11/12/2020  abb bbc abb Bad Good
1   12/10/2020  xyz xxy Good    Good
2   11/24/2020  tyu yuu Neutral Good
3   12/16/2020  iop yui Bad Good
```

Comment: Thanks, but the value is not always good. it can be bad and neutral also

Comment: I have edited the result to have better clarity

Comment: I realize that but can't figure your logic for determining the value, as I indicated in the compare_data function.  If you can explain the logic behind setting the value, I will happily edit the code/

Comment: Yes sure, So everyday there are news coming from different source for which I have built the Sentiment Model. Now, the task is based on the Sentiment predicted for that particular day, I need to return a sentiment based on condition mentioned in the function and write it a column called 'Day_Sentiment' . 

For example, in a day I get 5 rows of data, out of which 2 are predicted as Good, 1 as Bad, and 2 as Neutral. I need to use above function to return as either of the three

Comment: Okay, I understand the Sentiment column, but what is the function you are trying to perform?  Where are you grouping the data by date?  In the example provided, I don't understand how this function works?

Comment: Can you write a statement that provides the contents of Day_Sentiment for each of the possible states based on the example data?

Comment: I havent grouped by date yet, and I have provided with an example in the question. First example refers to the data i have mentioned. 2nd example s for refernce

Comment: You still haven't shown us how to compute Day_Sentiment given the example data.  I have no idea what determines the value of Day_Sentiment so can't help.

Comment: It is cmputed by no. of bad sentiment, no.of good sentiments and neutral sentiments as i have mentioned now in the function

Comment: How can yo compute the number of Good, Bad, Neutral Sentiments for a single row of the table?  I can total the number of Good, Bad, & Neutral Sentiments for the df and then set the Day_sentiment = to the result but that will give a single value for all rows.  Is this what you want?